# howto get a flash object (swf) variables

Tags: flash, flashvars

I need to know if there's a way (a tool) to get a flash object (swf) variables which are used in "flashvar" tag.

Answer (score 0):

You access the variables using:

```
   loaderInfo.parameters
```

http://circlecube.com/2009/12/flashvars-and-as3/

Answer (score 0):

With flex into the mx:application :

```
Application.application.parameters.myName
```

Otherwise:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters[myName];
```

With flash application from a displayed object:

```
LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
```